# (0xC03A0014) Failed to add device 'Microsoft Virtual Hard Disk'

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, vhd

We had Windows 2008 SP2 Server. It was crashed due to mother board problem. After we got new motherboard we have installed Windows 2008 R2. Now when we try to attach Old VHD File we are getting following issue.

Failed to add device 'Microsoft Virtual Hard Disk'.

Cannot open attachment 'D:\Test\test.vhd'. Error: 'A virtual disk support provider for the specified file was not found.'

TestVM': Cannot open attachment 'D:\Test\test.vhd'. Error: 'A virtual disk support provider for the specified file was not found.' (0xC03A0014). (Virtual machine ID 5626AAB2-C21C-48FF-8B70-40671CBC573B)

Comment: Are you attaching the .vhd as a disk in Disk Management, or actually adding a VM and using this .vhd using the Hyper-V manager?

Comment: Why do you have tags for both 2008 and 2008R2? Which one is it?

Comment: @DanBig - I am trying to attach .vhd disk in Hyper-V manager. I have tried to attach in Disk Management that is working fine only problem is with New VM when I try to attach old VHD that is creating problem.

Comment: @Chris S My Old System was Windows 2008 and My New System is Windows 2008 R2 so I have tag both.

Comment: Were there snapshots on the VM?

Answer (score 1):

I have got answer for my question. Following URL helped me with the same.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/f2c5731f-7c26-4a04-96ae-3a4eeca0a2cd

I have made "Network Service" member of Administrative group and that worked for me.

Comment: That is not a good idea from a security perspective. The Network Service account is supposed to have very limited privileges for a reason.